# javascript how to get element that is currently not visible

Tags: javascript, element

I want to get the element that is not visible in window. Is there a function like `document.getElementFromPoint(x,y)`, that works in this situation?

In my particular case I have 2 layers on page, droppable and main one. I have a particular droppable div, I save the droppable div in variable, then I scroll down, the droppable div stops being visible. At that moment I want to be able to get the top element on that droppable div position.

Comment: You want to get *any random element* not currently visible…? You can get any element on the page using the standard selection of `getElementBy*`, whether the element is visible or not…

Comment: Sorry part of my post didn't save, edited

Comment: *Is there a function like `document.getElementFromPoint(x,y)`* no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find an element off the top of the view port: iterate through all elements until you find one where `el.getBoundingClientRect().bottom` is negative (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)).

A more general solution could apply look for multiple criteria including off the side or bottom by comparing the results to the size of the view port (eg. bounding rectangle's `top` being greater than the client size of the Window).

Comment: (This reflects an earlier version of the question; but the key API allows operations based on the position of an element in the document or to be compared to the view port.)